# Variadic template specialization in C++11

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, g++, clang++

Is it implemented already, because this does not compile: (using gcc 4.7.2)

```
template <typename... Ts>
struct Foo {
    int foo() {
        return 0;
    }
};

template <>
struct Foo<int x, int y> {
    int foo() {
        return x * y;
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<2, 3> x;
    cout << x.foo() << endl; //should print 6
}
```

Comment: If it does not compile, what is the compiler complaining about?

Comment: Variadic templates have long been implemented in gcc. If you want to check for feature support: http://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are making a few mistakes. The primary template expects types, not
integral constants. You also try to instantiate the template with
integral constants, but your partial specialization uses types.

This is closer:

```
#include <iostream>

template <int... Ts>
struct Foo {
    int foo() {
        return 0;
    }
};

template <>
struct Foo<3, 2> {
  const int x = 3;
  const int y = 2;

  int foo() {
    return x * y;
  }
};

int main()
{
    Foo<2, 3> x;
    std::cout << x.foo() << std::endl; //should print 6
}
```

But this is not really what we want, right? And it is also clumsy.

```
#include <iostream>

template<typename Acc, typename... Rest>
struct accum_help; // primary

template<typename Acc, typename F, typename... Rest>
struct accum_help<Acc, F, Rest...> {
  typedef typename accum_help<
    std::integral_constant<typename Acc::value_type, 
                           Acc::value * F::value>, Rest...
    >::type type;
};

template<typename Acc>
struct accum_help<Acc> {
  typedef Acc type;
};

// peek into the first argument to avoid summing empty sequences and
// get the right type
template<typename X, typename... Integrals>
struct accum {
  typedef typename accum_help<
    std::integral_constant<typename X::value_type, 1>, X, Integrals...
    >::type type;
};

int main()
{

  std::cout << accum< std::integral_constant<int, 2>, std::integral_constant<int, 3> >::type::value << std::endl; //should print 6
}
```

A simpler variant handling only int:

```
template <int...>
struct accum2_help;

template <int Acc, int X, int... Rest> 
struct accum2_help<Acc, X, Rest...> {
  static const int value = accum2_help< Acc * X, Rest...>::value;
};

template <int Acc>
struct accum2_help<Acc> {
  static const int value = Acc;
};

// again don't accept empty packs
template <int T, int... Ts>
struct accum2 {
  static const int value = accum2_help<1, T, Ts...>::value;
};
```

Comment: So how to do this: 1. Declare the `<int,int>` version of `Foo` and instantiate it with the constants `<2, 3>`?

Comment: `Foo<2, 3> x`? Should it not be `Foo<3, 2> x`?

Comment: @Martin If you want to be able to use `Foo` as `Foo<2, 3>`, then it looks like the primary template you want is something like `template<int... I> struct Foo;`.

Comment: @martin I added a general accumulator that does multiplication. There are several levels of abstraction that you can still get out of this, but it shows the general theme.