# C++ Variadic template method specialization

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

I have some variadic template method, which looks like this:

```
    template<typename ... Args>
    void Invoke(const char* funcName, Args ... args) const;

    template<typename ... Args>
    void Invoke(const char* funcName, Args ... args) const
    {
        SPrimitive params[] = { args ... };
        SomeOtherInvoke(funcName, params, sizeof ... (Args));
    }
```

Here SPrimitive - just a simple struct with a constructor for any primitive type.

I want to make one more Invoke definition for some complex type. And here is my question:
Is it possible to make variadic template method specialization in c++ 11/14 ?
I mean something like this ( for simplicity lets my type will be int):

```
    template<int ... Args>
    void Invoke(const char* funcName, Args ... args)
    {
        int params[] = { args ... };
        SomeComplexInvoke(funcName, params, sizeof ... (Args));
    }
```

Here I want a specialization, which takes any parameters count of type int, so I can call it just like this:

```
    Invoke("method", 2, 4 ,9);
```

Comment: Not with specialization, but you can with overload and SFINAE.

Comment: but `std::initializer_list<T>` seems more appropriate (with `Invoke("method" {2, 4, 9})` syntax).

Comment: @Jarod42 I have seen `template<int... args>` [elsewhere](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13515795/); can that not be used somehow for variadic function templates specialized for a variable number of int arguments?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As @Jarod42 mentioned, it should not be done with specialization. In your example you want something special if all argument types are `int`, so let's write a template which will check it:

```
template<typename ref, typename t, typename ...types>
struct all_same {
        static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<ref, t>::value && all_same<ref, types...>::value;
};

template<typename ref, typename t>
struct all_same<ref, t> {
        static constexpr bool value = std::is_same<ref, t>::value;
};
```

It checks whether first type argument is equal to all other type arguments. Then in `Invoke` we should select `params` type based on `args...` types:

```
template<typename ... Args>
void Invoke(const char* funcName, Args ... args)
{
    using params_type = typename std::conditional<all_same<int, Args...>::value, int, SPrimitive>::type;
    params_type params[] = { args ... };
    SomeOtherInvoke(funcName, params, sizeof ... (Args));
}
```

Now for the sake of demonstration let's define:

```
struct SPrimitive{
};

void SomeOtherInvoke(const char*, SPrimitive*, size_t) {
        std::cout << "Invoked for SPrimitive\n";
}

void SomeOtherInvoke(const char*, int*, size_t) {
        std::cout << "Invoked for int\n";
}
```

and call

```
Invoke("foo", SPrimitive());
Invoke("foo", SPrimitive(), SPrimitive());
Invoke("foo", 1, 2, 3, 4);
```

The output is:

```
Invoked for SPrimitive
Invoked for SPrimitive
Invoked for int
```

which is what you asked for.

Comment: Thanks, its exactly what I am looking for!

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem and found a simpler method. The idea is to just use a simple static_cast.

```
template <class ...args
void test (args ...a)
{
 test___( sizeof... (a), static_cast<int*>(&a)... );
}

extern void test___(int count,...);
```

Note:

- I intentional used c ellipsis to show that you can simply  pass  cpp variadic arguments to c ellipsis parameters. Is this cpp universal? I dont know.
- Also to let you know how convenient it is to use best of both worlds. Cpp variadic functions are clunky to write. C ellipsis are not type aware and this can really matter.
- Finally note how we can use the address of operator on the variadic argument. Is this cpp universal? I dont know.

I want to end with a case where c ellipsis are clunky and cpp combined with c saved me.

```
//This function expects RECT pointers
void addRect (int count,...);

int main () 
{
 RECT r = {0,0,640,480};
 addRect (3,r,r,r}; // However it is so easy to forget that
                              // program will crash
}
```

So instead, write the public method as a variadic function, which in turn passes the right thing the ellipsis version.

Note: Everything could be done via cpp variadics, but it is clunky and looks awful alot of the times.

Comment: Yes, passing an expanded parameter pack to a C variadic function is well-defined, as long as the argument types are supported in the first place. The template instantiation just converts the pack expansion to a list of expressions, and then the rules for calling a C variadic function apply as usual.

Comment: But C variadic functions have some limitations which make them quite awkward too: Passing any non-trivial class type is only conditionally supported. If you want to deal with different possible argument types, you'll need to encode the list of types from compile-time information to runtime and then decode that in the implementation (and better get it right!). I can't really imagine many cases where I'd rather use `<cstdarg>` than variadic templates.

Comment: Your first function just fails to compile if any argument passed is not an `int` (including an `unsigned int`). This doesn't seem helpful for the wanted overload of an existing general function.

Comment: Failing to compile if the argument is not convertible to int is the purpose of my static_cast. And no, it will definately not fail to unsigned int as unsigned int is convertible to int via promotion. Have you tested it? I havent but I am certain it works. Understand that any code being called inside the template has already been instantiated and thus is no longer under the limitation of template conversions.

Comment: `static_cast` from `unsigned int*` to `int*` is ill-formed. To get `int` objects, you would need a local array. I think `reinterpret_cast` would be legal on `unsigned int*` but leads to undefined behavior for any other type.

Comment: @aschepler I now realize the technical path you are going. For one thing, I could have just used int instead of int pointer for my example. int pointer was used as the c ellipsis function is expecting int pointer, in my contrived  example. Secondly, I dont know what standard you are reading, but I know static_cast to be 100% safe. If the type is not convertible, all that will happen is a compile error. As far as I know. In this, case where the c ellipsis function is expecting int* (or it could even have been std::string* to avoid confusion); we expect passing an unsigned int pointer to fail.

Answer (score 0):

I already gave an alternative answer. Now here is another. Note I still give credence to the person that did the first answer; and his answer is useful as an intellectual demonstration and may have its place and time.

Note: My alternatives accept anything convertible to int. While his suggestion only accepts int and will not accept int& unless you use std::remove_reference. It is rather complicated.

This alternative is based on template overloading. If we want a function that accepts only ints or objects convertible  to ints; we simply add int as the first parameter of our variadic template function!

```
template <class ...args>
void example (int i,args ...rest)
{
 example__(sizeof... (rest)+1, i, rest...);
}

void example (int count,...);
```

Note: again everything could have been done with Cpp Variadics. But I think C ellipsis really makes the task much simplier and less compilation errors, and a slim chance of runtime error if you remember to pass only primitives and pointers to C ellipsis.

If you want your function to accept multiple types in one function call you do the following. I will omit the private implementation function and the public implementation.

```
template <class ...args>
void example (int i,args &...rest);

template <class ...args>
void example (const std::string&, args &...rest);
```

Finally, if you want your function to accept various types, but in seperate function calls, I suggest using a naming convention.

```
template <class ...args>
void intExample (int i,args &...rest);

template <class ...args>
void stringExample (const std::string&, args &...rest);

template <class ...args>
int getInt (int i,args &...rest);

template <class ...args>
std::string getString (const std::string&, args &...rest);
```

Note: By keeping the first parameter in the final examples, you ensure that atleast one argument has to be passed to your function.

Well, that is all for today. If you made it this far you are awesome. Thank you for watching. If you love my videos; click that subscribe button. Smash that like button.

******Edit******_
I discovered a beauty in Cpp Variadics I wish to showcase here. As you know Cpp templates is pretty C macro that is type safe and namespace respecting.

```
struct ColumnStyle
{
 int type;
 int align;
 int width;
 int min_width;
 int max_width;
 Int margin;
};
```

I want to extend this class, but I want it to still behave as an aggregate class.

```
struct LogColumn : ColumnStyle
{
 template <class ...args>
 LogColumn (const wchar_t *caption, HBITMAP icon, args ...style)
  : ColumnStyle {style...}, // amazing! I can simply pass the variadic arguments to the aggregate ctor!
    header_caption (caption),
    header_icon (icon)
  {}

 const wchart_t *header_caption;
 HBITMAP header_icon;
};
```